# Crashing MR-3020

Tags: python, linux

I've got several MR-3020's that I have flashed with OpenWRT and mounted a 16GB ext4 USB drive on it. Upon boot, a daemon shell script is started which does two things:

1) It constantly looks to see if my main program is running and if not starts up the python script
2) It compares the lasts heartbeat timestamp generated by my main program and if it is older than 10 minutes in the past kills the python process. #1 is then supposed to restart it.

Once running, my main script goes into monitor mode and collects packet information. It periodically stops sniffing, connects to the internet and uploads the data to my server, saves the heartbeat timestamp and then goes back into monitor mode.

This will run for a couple hours, days, or even a few weeks but always seems to die at some point. I've been having this issue for nearly 6 months (not exclusively) I've run out of ideas. I've got files for error, info and debug level logging on pretty much every line in the python script. The amount of memory used by the python process seems to hold steady. All network calls are encapsulated in try/catch statements. The daemon writes to logread. Even with all that logging, I can't seem to track down what the issue might be. There doesn't seem to be any endless loops entered into, none of the errors (usually HTTP request when not connected to internet yet) are ever the final log record - the device just seems to freeze up randomly.

Any advice on how to further track this down?

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to many things: things that I had to fix also: check the external power supply of the router, needs to be  stable, the usb drives could drain too much current than the port can handle, a simple fix is to add a externally powered usbhub or the same port but with capacitors in parallel to the powerline and at the beginning of the usb port where the drive is, maybe 1000uF